# Ionic 3 Video pauses after 1 second of playing in IOS 13.3

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, ios13, ios13.3

Ionic 3 Video pauses after 1 second of playing in IOS 13.3, video works in older versions of IOS.

```
<ion-content padding>
   <video width="100%" height="100%" controls autoplay>
      <source src="{{videoURL}}" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</ion-content>
```

but works perfectly while we play the video muted

```
<ion-content padding>
   <video width="100%" height="100%" controls autoplay muted>
      <source src="{{videoURL}}" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Try muted attribute with false value E.g: `<video muted="false"></video>`

Comment: Hello! You can resolv it?